# Understanding hierarchical clustering features importance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, clustering, explainable-ai, agglomerative

I made a hierarchical clustering with scikit :

```
selected_model = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=8)
hierarchical_clustering8 = selected_model.fit_predict(answers)
```

This classification was done on the basis of 50 features and led me to 8 clusters.

How can I proceed to determine the importance of each feature in this classification ?

My goal is to determine the most important and least important features for each cluster, and to be able to explain each cluster.

Comment: Try PCA which will give you the variance of each feature which in turn might be a good indicator of feature importance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a estimator trained and ready. You can use the created classes and train a classification mode based on these classes. I would try a [Random Forest Classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) which has a built in feature importance attribute. This attribute indicates the information gain that the features impose.